# Detecting Geometric shapes using Simplecv

Tags: edge-detection, simplecv

I am working on a personal project which require using Simplecv to detect geometric shape using edge detection. I am planning to place my raspberry pi on top of a toy car which would move based on the shape the raspberry pi's camera detects while moving. Which means that if the camera comes across a circle then the car should stop moving and so on.

Could someone provide me some pointers on how should I go about detecting and differentiating geometric  shapes using SImpleCV and edge detection. My reasoning of using edge detection is to make the processing data as small as possible and I am using Simplecv because I am new to computer vision and I feel that SimpleCV is a good introduction to computer vision.

I would really appreciate your help,

Thanks,